# How to increase download speed, enable pause/resume , speed rate of Windows ClickOnce installer download manager?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, clickonce

The windows application I am testing have a click once installer.
The application size is 1.25gb (contains some files, msi installers etc) and download speed rate is happening always throttled to max speed of 2.7mbps. Takes 1+ hrs. This click once download happens from azure cloud with APIM. Wondering where is this **download speed limit** configured? How a user can utilize their available bandwidth for fast download from the click once hosted server? Now users are forced to wait for 1+ hours always.

[image]

Another question is how to enable **download speed rate** in the download manager, And **pause/resume** in the click once downloader (dfsvc.exe)?

Couldn't find much details about handling download speed rate, enable pause/resume of click once installer from the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2022

Comment: 1.25GB is a very large app to be using ClickOnce. If it's just a handful of big resource files, maybe find another way to load them rather than embedding them into the app.